# Get number of reservation based on dates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I get total number of bookings if I pass **from** as "1970-01-01" and **to** as "1970-01-05"?

**Reserved** array contains all the booked rooms with **from** to **to** dates

Here is my data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c0a17013d8ca91bf4ee7885",
    "name": "ABC",
    "reserved": [
      {
        "from": "1970-01-01",
        "to": "1970-01-02",
        "isCompleted": false
      },
      {
        "from": "1970-01-03",
        "to": "1970-01-05",
        "isCompleted": false
      },
      {
        "from": "2017-04-18",
        "to": "2017-04-23",
        "isCompleted": false
      },
      {
        "from": "2018-01-29",
        "to": "2018-01-30",
        "isCompleted": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried to get data using find query (I know that's not correct)

```
db.collection.find({
  reserved: {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        from: {
          $lt: "1970-01-07"
        },
        to: {
          $gt: "1970-01-05"
        },
        "isCompleted": true
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: What is the query you're trying?

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta I'll update my code.  Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a pipeline that utilises the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator on a filtered array. For filtering you would need the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator and your condition would be an AND on the [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) and [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/)
comparison operator i.e.

```
{ 
    "$and": [
        { "$gte": [ < from field >, "1970-01-01"] },
        { "$lte": [ < to field >, "1970-01-05"] }
    ]
}
```

So you overall aggregate operation would be something like the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
        "totalBookings": {
            "$size": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$reserved",
                    "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$gte": ["$$this.from", "1970-01-01"] },
                            { "$lte": ["$$this.to", "1970-01-05"] }
                        ]
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

Comment: How can I modify this query to get unique booking counter? Like If I pass from date as "1970-01-01" and to date as "1970-01-05" then it will return me only 1. Because there is two booking but that's on different date (One is from 1970-01-01 to 1970-01-02 and another is from "1970-01-03" to "1970-01-05").

Comment: @HarshPatel Did this answer your original question though? It is considered bad practice here on SO and very misleading to people who come along and see that answers provided do not match what you have asked. The general case here is one question one answer. I will be more than happy to answer the additional question but it should be another question entirely

Comment: Yes this is answer of this question, I realise before you told me. Sorry for the inconvenience. Here is the new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54322947/get-unique-number-of-reservation-based-on-dates)

Comment: I'm still looking for the solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to check if those timespans overlap each other which means that `reserved.from` `<=`  `to` and `reserved.to` `>=` `from`. To easily deal with nested array you can start with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and then use [$count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/index.html) to get total number of matching documents, try:

```
var from = "1970-01-01";
var to = "1970-01-05";

db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$reserved" },
    {
        $match: { "reserved.from": { $lte: to }, "reserved.to": { $gte: from  } }
    },
    {
        $count: "total"
    }
])
```

Comment: @mickl, the dates are in string format, will $lte, $gte work?

Comment: How can I modify this query to get unique booking counter? Like If I pass from date as "1970-01-01" and to date as "1970-01-05" then it will return me only 1. Because there is two booking but that's on different date (One is from 1970-01-01 to 1970-01-02 and another is from "1970-01-03" to "1970-01-05").

Comment: Here is the new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54322947/get-unique-number-of-reservation-based-on-dates) Please answer there